# Laravel authentication package

Tags: laravel

I have been using CodeIgniter with Ion Auth for authentication. I am making the switch to Laravel and I am wondering if there is anything similar? Or what the popular authentication packages are. I am looking to implement various permission types. (ex. admin, basic user, power user)

Comment: Authentication is built in. There are a variety of packages for more complex user management, like Cartalyst's Sentry. That said, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."

Comment: I am aware of the built in authentication. I guess I was thinking more of a library to handle activation emails, forgot password, active/deactivate users etc. I apologize for the improper question.

Comment: Cartalyst Sentry does all that and is free. https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry